# Frequency Array and Histogram in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have to make the following program.
Write a program that builds a frequency array for data values in the range 1 to 20 and then prints their histogram. The data is to be read as input from the user. Add the following functions to your program:
a. The getData function takes input from the user and stores the data in an array.
b. The printData function prints the data in the array.
c. The makeFrequency function examines the data in the array, one element at a time, and adds 1 to the corresponding element in a frequency array based on the data value.
d. The makeHistogram function prints out a vertical histogram using asterisks for each occurrence of an element. For example, if there were five value 1s and eight value 2s in the data, it would print
`1: *****`
`2: ********`
I managed to make getData function but I can't make the other 3. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FrequencyArray {
static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public void getData() {
    System.out.println("Enter the size of array: ");
    int nums = scan.nextInt();
    int[] a = new int[nums];
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter the numbers: " + i + ":");
        a[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }
}

public void printData() {
    getData();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FrequencyArray array = new FrequencyArray();
    array.getData();
}
}
```

Comment: Rewrite your post to make your problem clear as opposed to a block of text comprised of your assignment and problem.

Comment: Change variable `a` to be a field, otherwise it won't be available to the other methods. Come back when you then have some more code, because you obviously know how to write print statements and loops, so item b should not be a problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

To print such an array, all you would need is another `for-loop` - loop from 0 to the array's length, and print both the loop counter's value, and the value stored in the array at that index.

```
System.out.println(index + ":" + array[index]);
```

For the histogram, do a similar loop, but for each value of the array, append an asterisk to the current line for however many instances of said number there are.

```
System.out.print(index);
//from 0 to the amount of this number, call System.out.print("*");
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Here I made a printData method like you said sir
public void printData() {
  int nums = scan.nextInt();
  int[] b = new int[nums];
  for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
   System.out.println(j + ":" + b[j]);
  }
 }
Is this right?
@Dimitri Velovski

Answer (score 0):

Use TreeMap to store the number and their frequency in a sorted order once you get the data

then iterate over the TreeMap to print the number followed by the stars denoting the count of the value

```
    public void printData() {
        int [] numArray = getData();
        Map<Integer,Integer> valueCountMap = new TreeMap();
        for(int i=0;i<numArray.length;i++) {
        int num = numArray[i];
        if(valueCountMap.get(num) == null) {
            valueCountMap.put(num,0);
        }
        int count = valueCountMap.get(num);
        valueCountMap.put(num,count+1);
        }
        for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry:valueCountMap.entrySet()) {
            int num = entry.getKey();
            int value = entry.getValue();
            System.out.print(num+":");
            for(int i=0;i<value;i++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
         System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
```

Following assumptions i have made getData must return interger array and you need to print in one line. Following rectification i have done to your code
in getData i = 0 not i = 1

Comment: But I haven't learned treemap method yet. So it's difficult for me to understand. By the way Thanks. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Do one thing instead of storing in TreeMap you can do one thing sort the array using Arrays.sort(numArray) then use the below algorithm

Comment: int num=numArray[i];     
    System,out.print(num+":");
    for(int i=1;i<numArray.length;i++)  {                                                                   
      if(numArray[i]==num) {
          System.out.print("*")
      }
      else {
        num = numArray[i]
        System.out.print(" ")
      }
}

Comment: basically you store the firstElement of the array in a variable called X and iterate over the array to see whether the current number of the array is equal to X if it is equal print * else update the value of X to currentNumber and print the number followed by a colon